# joomla template index.php with jquery

Tags: jquery, joomla1.7, joomla-template

In my joomla template, I removed the link to the stylesheet in the head section of index.php and instead added the following jquery code to chosse the stylesheet used that is based on screen width

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    if (screen.width <= 1024) 
    {
      $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="style2.css" type="text/css"/>');
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() 
{
    if (screen.width > 1024)
    {
       $('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" href="template.css" type="text/css/>');
    }
}
</script>
```

when I load the website in the browser, no stylesheet is used.  I don't understand what is wrong.  Thanks in advance

EvilP, thanks for the response, yes the css is located in the same location as index.php

Comment: is the link to your css valid ? Is your page really located in the same directory as the current page

Comment: I do know this is sth different but have you thought of using CSS3 Media Queries? See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/NLdLZ/ and these docs: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Comment: BTW you are missing a `"` in your second append where it should say `...type="text/css"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do that with javascript, you should use media queries to provide different styles fpr different screen size

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 768px)
and (max-device-width : 1024px)
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```